# Propagating non-null values forward up to the last entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that looks similar to this:
[image]

As you can tell, there are plenty of blanks. I want to propagate non-null values forward (so for example, in the first row *1029* goes to *1963.02.12* column, between *1029* and *1043*) but only up to the last entry, that is it should stop propagating when it encounters the last non-null value (for D it would be 
 the 1992.03.23 column, but for A it'd be 1963.09.21, just outside the screenshot).

Is there a quicker way to achieve this without fiddling around with `df.fillna(method='ffill', limit=x)`? My original idea was to remember the date of the last entry, propagate values to the end of the row, and then fill the row with nulls after the saved date. I've been wondering if there is a cleverer method to achieve the same result.

Comment: Does `df.ffill(axis=1)` not satisfy?

Comment: Good explanation of propagating non-null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be very performant. I couldn't get a pure-pandas solution (which obviously doesn't guarantee performance anyway!)

```
>>> df
     a    b    c    d    e
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN  4.0
```

What happens if we just `ffill` everything?

```
>>> df.ffill(axis=1)
     a    b    c    d    e
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  2.0  4.0
```

We need to go back and add NaNs for the last null column in each row:

```
>>> new_data = []
>>> for _, row in df.iterrows():
...     new_row = row.ffill()
...     null_columns = [col for col, is_null in zip(row.index, row.isnull().values) if is_null]
...     # replace value in last column with NaN
...     if null_columns:
...         last_null_column = null_columns[-1]
...         new_row.ix[last_null_column] = np.nan
...     new_data.append(new_row.to_dict())
... 
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_data)
>>> new_df
     a    b    c    d    e
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: It fails to stop propagating after the cut-off date - it propagates all the way up to the last date present in the DataFrame while I want to have it propagate to the last date present in respective rows.

Comment: So basically you ffill until the last NaN in each row, then leave that last NaN, well as a NaN?

Comment: Indeed, yes. The superficial reason for that is that they won't get plotted on the chart as matplotlib doesn't plot NaNs, which is a dirty way to get rid of values from the '60s when I'm plotting, for example, 2010s.

Comment: After a slight modification related to the nature of my data it did the trick, thanks a lot!